# What's the rationale behind the expression 'Air-mile-heavy'?

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin

I came across this bit today at The Guardian:

[*"And by giving Mr Johnson such an air-mile-heavy job she gave him plenty of time-consuming activities, all of them well away from Westminster."*](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/nov/16/the-guardian-view-on-boris-johnson-he-is-causing-too-much-needless-chaos)

I assume 'air-mile-heavy job' means 'a difficult job' in this context, but I can't quite understand the connection between something so abstract and light as an 'air-mile' to something being arduous.

Any idea on how common this expression is?

Does anyone know where does it come from?

Comment: Not a common expression, but I have heard similar things once or twice.  It implies a lot of flying back and forth, which is quite tedious and stressful, and which (I think the article implies) keeps the individual incommunicado for great periods of time.

Comment: It means lotsof travel....

Comment: This is a simple case of somene putting words next to each other to make it mean what they want it to mean. It’s not an idiom or set  phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**air-mile-heavy** means it results in lots of air-miles, which could mean the redeemable points ...
[EDIT]
 **or** the more prosaic *distance covered.*

> **Air Miles**.
>   *trademark* Points (equivalent to miles of free air travel) accumulated by buyers of airline tickets and other products and redeemable against the cost of air travel with a particular airline.
>   — [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/air_mile)

Comment: Maybe. With *frequent flyer miles* it would be unambiguously so, but one could also use *air miles* in references to distance traveled by air. Some business travelers rack up the *air miles*, but others rack up the *road miles*, and neither need be enrolled in any kind of distance-based loyalty program.

Comment: Yeah, "air miles" does not necessarily refer to racking up "points".  It's quite common to say something like "It's 2300 air miles to East Podunk from here."

Comment: @choster and HotLicks Fair points. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I came across exactly the same question reading this article and would suggest : a job in which you travel a lot, thus piling air miles